# model.fit() IndexError list index out of range

Tags: python, keras

Here is my code:

```py
def baseline_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
    return model


model = baseline_model()
model.compile(loss="bce", optimizer="SGD", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(
    train_x,
    train_y,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(val_x, val_y),
)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> length of train_x=20, val_x=6, train_y=20, val_y=6
> Train and split is working properly  model.fit is giving error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What are the values of `batch_size` and `input_shape`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index Out of Range tensorflow keras with model.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051147/index-out-of-range-tensorflow-keras-with-model-fit)